# How to share a modifed moderncvclassic.sty file and give credits the right way?

Tags: packages, moderncv, licensing

I have tweaked the moderncvstyleclassic.sty file from the moderncv package and implemented more commands to comply with the belgian/french layout rules for official mail. All of my modifications are in a new moderncvfrench.sty file and rely on moderncv.cls and other files bundled with the moderncv package.

I would like to share it (presumably via github ?) but I don't know how I should phrase the header of the file regarding the LPPL. I don't want to infringe on the original author's copyright but I also need to state I am the one responsible for the modified style so that people won't bother him with support for something he isn't responsible for.

I asked at launchpad but my question was expired because it remained in the 'Open' state too long.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use (have used/do use) something like this at the top of the file:

```
%% moderncvfrench.sty
%% Additions and changes are copyright 2013 YOUR NAME
%% Code from moderncvstyleclassic.sty copyright YYYY ORIGINAL AUTHOR'S NAME (see below)
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is YOUR NAME.
%
% This work consists of the file moderncvfrench.sty.
%
% The file moderncvfrench.sty is a derived work under the terms of the 
% LPPL. It is based on version VERSION of moderncvstyleclassic.sty which is 
% part of the moderncv package by ORIGINAL AUTHOR'S NAME. A copy of moderncv,
% including the unmodified version of moderncvstyleclassic.sty is available
% from URL-FOR-ORIGINAL-ON-CTAN.
% moderncvstyleclassic.sty is part of the included archive ARCHIVE.tar.gz
% which is released under the LPPL.
% moderncvstyleclassic.sty is FURTHER INSTRUCTIONS TO LOCATE ORIGINAL IF NEEDED.
%
```

Substitute details as appropriate.